# Jerky framerate when traversing image across screen

Tags: python, performance, pygame, frame-rate

I'm wondering if this is a limitation of pygame or if I'm doing it wrong. When I move an image across the screen, the framerate is variable and slow. I'd really like to make it smooth. My code is:

```html
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 1)
map = pygame.image.load('test_2000x1333.jpg')

camera_x = -320
camera_y = -250

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_running = True

while game_running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key_pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            if camera_y < 0:
                camera_y += 2
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            if camera_y > -550:
                camera_y -= 2
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            if camera_x < 0:
                camera_x += 2
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            if camera_x > -630:
                camera_x -= 2

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_ALT:
                if event.key == pygame.K_F4:
                    game_running = False

    screen.blit(map, (camera_x, camera_y))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

I've tried adding 'pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.HWSURFACE' to the display.set_mode flag, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Loaded images should usually be converted with the [`convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or `convert_alpha` methods to improve the performance: `map = pygame.image.load('test_2000x1333.jpg').convert()`. Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

With that image size, I suspect you're trying to do this on a Raspberry Pi, Android or some other device that isn't accelerate by PyGame. To quote:

> The Raspberry Pi is a slow CPU with a very powerful GPU. Pygame does not natively leverage the GPU, resulting in the poor performance you are experiencing. To leverage the GPU, you need to find a library for your programming language that works with OpenGLES, OpenVG, etc. Luckily, there are a few libraries that greatly simplify this - here are some examples:
>   pi3D and Simple2D.
>   There are others depending on which language you want to use.
>   Also, the [Graphics Programming Forum on the Raspberry Pi Forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=67&sid=8a98a2826fe6ac0e95f750bccfeb8365) is quite helpful at learning how to get the most performance out of the Raspberry Pi GPU.
>   If you want a sense of how powerful the GPU is, check out the hello_video series of demos that are included with Raspbian - [Raspberry Pi Demo Programs](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/demos/)

There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 with a 1920x1080 display, Core i5-4430 and GTX 760. I tried map = pygame.image.load('test_2000x1333.jpg').convert() and .convert_alpha(), but I don't see a performance improvement.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't anything really wrong with what you've written. PyGame isn't meaningfully accelerated in 2D and you're doing the slowest possible operation here, which is a full-screen redraw. There might be a degenerate setup for you if you're using Anaconda or something, I'm only speculating. Naturally with a computer that fast there shouldn't be any problems. Your best bet will be to use a different Python game kit not based on pyGame.